# jpg is not displaying in liferay jsp page

Tags: html, liferay, jpeg

I am using Liferay and struts 2 framework. I want to display a jpg file.

My struts.xml is like:

```
<action name="searchAllCategoryWiseGraphical" class="com.stp.portal.view.SearchEFormReportPortlet" method="searchAllEFormsCategoryWiseGraphical" >
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/view/GraphicalViewPage.html</result>            
</action>
```

Now the bar chart is generated and is saved in a specified location in jpg format. I am writing simple html code to display the same:

```
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.Document"%>
<%@page import="org.codehaus.groovy.transform.powerassert.Value"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/view/MessagePage.jsp"/>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<s:form name="searchAllCategoryWiseGraphical" action="searchAllCategoryWiseGraphical" method="POST" theme="simple">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img border="0" src="D:/eFormReport_Vertical.jpg" alt="report" width="600" height="400">

</body>
</html>

</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

But the image is not displaying. If i am saving the html code in a separate html file(not in the liferay portal page), the graph is displaying. Is it some liferay issue or am i am missing something??

Thanks and Regards

------------EDITED-----------

Thanks for the reply. Yes, its a path issue. Its solved now. Now I am getting another problem. The graph will change depending upon the input values. But its showing only the first graph. I have replaced the old jpg with the new one keeping the same file name. But its not showing the latest jpg.

Comment: It's a path issue. Try using a relative path instead of absolute physical path.

Comment: see my updated answer..and if that answer solved your image path problem then accept the answer and ask new question for that

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem with js and css so what i have done is using relative path 
you can do same to get the images as it seems that its just path problem you facing.
put your images in `docroot` directory

```
<img border="0" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/eFormReport_Vertical.jpg" alt="report" width="600" height="400">
```

hope it helps..

just delete temp folder from the liferay server directory its using cache version of portal or you can restart the server and ctrl+f5 the browser window.. it will solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please see the edited portion.

Comment: I have deleted the temp folder and restart the server and clear the browsing history. After that the the change occurs for the first search, afte that, the same problem occurs, only the old jpg is showing, not the new ones.

Comment: may be its from your code now should be some problem..nothing from path side problem